# Why does IE9 and above throw undefined variable/sub error when IE8 doesn't

Tags: html, vbscript, internet-explorer-9, undefined

I recently discovered my vbscript code on an intranet site has been running in IE 8 Compatibility Mode by default because it's on the intranet.

Now the below code works great in IE8 compatibility mode but throws an error if ran in any compatbility mode higher than 8. Help me out please! :) Pretty please?

The error given in IE's developer console is: 'test' is undefined"

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>Test VBScript Code</title>

</head>

<script language="VBScript">        


Sub test

MsgBox "Hello World!"       

End Sub 

</script>


<body>

<input type="button" value="TEST" onclick="test">

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow. VBScript in the browser. Ouch. I thought I'd seen the last of that. No chance of converting to Javascript? Hmmm, anyway, possible issues, just off the top of my head: (1) Maybe you need to call `test()` with brackets, otherwise it will think you're refencing a variable name? (2) the `language` attribute for `<script>` tag is deprecated; use `type='text/vbscript'` instead.

Comment: I need this for intranet stuff. Not public stuff. I don't know JavaScript very well but I know vbscript quite well. So no, if not absolutely necessary I won't convert to javascript. I've tried using parenthesizes on the sub to no avail. And also changed to use the type='text/vbscript'. Didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 has tighter security and has disabled the running of VBScript in the browser by default.

Here are simple steps to turn on or turn off VBScript in your Internet Explorer:

- Follow Tools-> Internet Options from the menu
- Select Security tab from the dialog box
- Click the Custom Level button
- Scroll down till you find Scripting option
- Select Enable radio button under Active scripting
- Finally click OK and come out

To disable VBScript support in your Internet Explorer, you need to select Disable radio button under Active scripting.